# Javascript Canvas, resize image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, blob, image-resizing

I wonder how to use canvas in JS. I have the following questions:

1. Let's say I have inputted an image and on my page I can access its **src** of **blob** (as far as I know this is the best way to get the image dynamically):

```
<img ... src="blob...">
```

Now I want to get this image in my JS and then modify it (resize and so on). Is blob src enough to do that?

2. When I'll resize the image with canvas, where to store that resized image? In **input** tag's value attribute or what? What's the best practice to resize image on front before sending it via network? That **input** is in my form as I want to send that resized image to my server, and not to overflow my network.
3. Also, is it possible to paste a watermark on that image with JS?

Hope you got it, and huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download and store your image as an [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) object, it's not necessary to have it in your html.

You can draw it on a canvas using [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) function, which let you draw the image with the proportion of your choice. You can use the same function to draw a watermark on the canvas.

Once you are happy with the image on the canvas you can get it as a blob using [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) function and upload to your server

Comment: Oh, that may be very useful. But what you mean by drawing an image? it is like a method name or what? You mean to draw the dynamically inputted image?

Comment: check out the links in the answer, you'll find documentation for all those functions (including `canvas.drawImage`)